# The app signature is different from that of the released version

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

I am trying to upload new apk with a keystore file and its giving this error. System says The app signature is different from that of the released version.

Answer (score 0):

The key-store which you have used for update release version should be consistent with the released version which there is in the app gallery.

If you don't have the key-store, you have to create new one and you can resubmit the application. If you create and resubmit with the new key-store, in that case you can leave a note saying Agree to ignore key-store difference in the Notes column of the Version information page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are releasing the app in apk format, please make sure the new app is signed with the same certificate as the one used previously.

If the app is going to be released using App Bundle, please confirm the upload signature is correct and auto-signing is enabled (or have your separate certificate for the app signing). The document from this link has more details on releasing the app in App Bundle format.